# How do I set a wireless static IP address on an OpenBSD 5.7 laptop?

Tags: openbsd

I have a typical laptop situation.  When I'm at my desk, I want to be hooked up to the network via ethernet, and when I want to sit on the back deck, I'd like to be on wireless.

I have ethernet setup for a static ip address, no problem.

I can connect wirelessly, but only via dhcpclient.  When I connect to the router, it assigns a conflicting ip address that makes my laptop fight with the kid's xbox. Not sure if it's the router or the xbox's fault, tbh.

Is it possible to connect wifi with a static ip address that I specify?  **I've read the man page for dhclient, ifconfig and read the faq**.  If the answer is in one of those documents, I've completely overlooked it a number of times.

Thanks in advance.

---

My current /etc/hostname.iwn0 looks like the following:

```
 inet 192.168.1.150 255.255.255.0 NONE
 nwid Portal
 wpakey passwordhidden
```

`sudo sh /etc/netstart iwn0` then `ping google.com` yields:

```
 PING google.com (198.231.29.34): 56 data bytes
 ping: sendto: Network is down
 ping: wrote google.com 64 chars, ret=-1
 2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

BUT, I can `sudo dhclient iwn0` and *then* ping google:

```
 1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
 round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 8.526/8.526/8.526/0.000 ms
```

So **the example in the FAQ doesn't work**, which is why I asked if there was something else that I might have missed.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the [FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#Wireless), which gives you a static IP address: you have to change your [hostname.if(5)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-5.7/man5/hostname.if.5) to something like

```
inet 10.0.0.157 255.255.255.0
nwid puffyuberalles
wpakey puffyguffy
```

Comment: I updated the original post since I don't have enough space in a comment to detail why what you sugguest doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect that you don't have a defaultroute. You can either set in in /etc/hostname.iwn0  (using `!route add default 192.168.1.1` or whatever your gateway is) or in /etc/mygate  (see `mygate(5)`)

Comment: Thomas Weinbrenner, you're a genius!